# WPF Binding stopped

Tags: wpf, binding

In code behind:

```
musicChooser.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedIndexProperty, musicIndexBinding);
```

When another button clicked:

```
musicChooser.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Then the Binding stopped, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explicitly removed binding by explicitly setting `-1` in following line.

```
  musicChooser.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

If you want to reset binding target, you need to reset binding source (musicIndexBinding in this case) value to `-1` and `mucisChooser` will pick it up.

Comment: I set SelectedItem instead.